# How to manually create a tf.Summary()

Tags: tensorflow

I often want to log python variables --as opposed to tf tensors.

In the docs it says that "you can pass a `tf.Summary` protocol buffer that you populate with your own data" but there is no docs for `tf.Summary` and i could not figure out how to use it.

Anyone knows how to create a Scalar summary this way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add an arbitrary value to a TensorFlow summary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37530228/how-do-i-add-an-arbitrary-value-to-a-tensorflow-summary)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can create a `tf.Summary` object in your Python program and write it to the same [`tf.summary.FileWriter`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/FileWriter) object that takes your TensorFlow-produced summaries using the [`SummaryWriter.add_summary()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/FileWriter#add_summary) method.

The `tf.Summary` class is a [Python protocol buffer wrapper](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated) for [the `Summary` protocol buffer](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/summary.proto). Each `Summary` contains a list of [`tf.Summary.Value`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/de1334da2c6e074c427d283898450de6e50a605d/tensorflow/core/framework/summary.proto#L64) protocol buffers, which each have a tag and a either a "simple" (floating-point scalar) value, an [image](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/de1334da2c6e074c427d283898450de6e50a605d/tensorflow/core/framework/summary.proto#L34), a [histogram](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/de1334da2c6e074c427d283898450de6e50a605d/tensorflow/core/framework/summary.proto#L11), or an [audio snippet](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/de1334da2c6e074c427d283898450de6e50a605d/tensorflow/core/framework/summary.proto#L51). For example, you can generate a scalar summary from a Python object as follows:

```
writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(...)
value = 37.0
summary = tf.Summary(value=[
    tf.Summary.Value(tag="summary_tag", simple_value=value), 
])
writer.add_summary(summary)
```

Comment: How to create an Image Summary instead?

Comment: I created a gist showing how to create image summaries:
https://gist.github.com/gyglim/1f8dfb1b5c82627ae3efcfbbadb9f514#file-tensorboard_logging-py-L41

Comment: Are the last three lines done every epoch? (I'm doing this from keras and trying to figure out where to put what - I'm guessing line 1 on my callback `__init__` and the rest `on_epoch_end()`?)

Comment: @HillarySanders I think that depends on how frequently you want to log things... (I'm not very familiar with Keras, but) the main choices seem to be putting it in an `on_epoch_end()` callback, or - for more frequent logs - putting it in an `on_batch_end()` callback (and maybe emitting data every *k* batches).

Comment: `tf.train.SummaryWriter` is deprecated, instead use `tf.summary.FileWriter`

Comment: How can you pass the current epoch to the summery as well?

Comment: If you want to store the global step as well, use `writer.add_summary(summary, global_step)`.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to log a python value you have to create a placeholder that have to be fed when running the `tf.Summary` op.

Here's a code snipped

```
value_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [])
summary_op = tf.scalar_summary("value_log", value_)
my_python_variable = 10
# define everything else you need...
# ...
with tf.Session() as sess:
    for i in range(0, 10):
        sess.run(summary_op, feed_dict={value_: my_python_variable*i})
```

Comment: Thanks but I was explicitly asking for a way to directly create a Summary protobuf so that i could avoid this cumbersome method.

Answer (score 4):

I needed to do many updates to the custom summary variable during training so I implemented mine like so:

**Before the loop:**

```
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(log_folder)
accuracy = None
accuracy_summary = tf.Summary()
accuracy_summary.value.add(tag='accuracy', simple_value=accuracy)
```

**Inside the loop:**

```
if i%20000 == 0:
    accuracy = get_accuracy()
    accuracy_summary.value[0].simple_value = accuracy
    writer.add_summary(accuracy_summary, i)
```

I'm assuming the indexes to `value` are in the order in which the variables were added to the summary.