# How is tf.summary.tensor_summary meant to be used?

Tags: tensorflow

TensorFlow provides a [`tf.summary.tensor_summary()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/tensor_summary) function that appears to be a multidimensional variant of [`tf.summary.scalar()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/scalar):

```py
tf.summary.tensor_summary(name, tensor, summary_description=None, collections=None)
```

I thought it could be useful for summarizing inferred probabilities per class ... somewhat like

```py
op_summary = tf.summary.tensor_summary('classes', some_tensor)
# ...
summary = sess.run(op_summary)
writer.add_summary(summary)
```

However it appears that TensorBoard doesn't provide a way to display these summaries at all. How are they meant to be used?

Comment: p_classes = t.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 10)) misses an f. Should be p_classes = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 10)). Or just a typo here?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but the placeholder is not an actual part of my question.

Comment: Is there any update to this question? I suspect it's been updated since the original post, and the TF documentation on this is baren.

Comment: It's another year later, and the tf docs still don't clarify this - my guess is it's meant to be for advanced users of the summary files?

Comment: oh yeah, check this out - maybe tensor_summary is meant for those developing plugins to tensorboard. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/01d9a34786ea0da087855f88ac32d0d7085c8266/tensorflow/python/summary/summary.py#L265

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot get it to work either. It seems like that feature is still under development. See this video from the TensorFlow Dev Summit that states that the tensor_summary is still under development (starting at 9:17): https://youtu.be/eBbEDRsCmv4?t=9m17s. It will probably be better defined and examples should be provided in the future.