# Why tensor_summary doesn't work?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I use `tf.summary.tensor_summary` in my code, following this: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/tensor_summary

But I didn't see anything new in tensorboard, and tensorboard also printed some warnings:

```
W0321 12:50:47.244003 Reloader tf_logging.py:121] This summary with tag 'component_3_finalize/wealth_tensor' is oddly not associated with a plugin.
```

How to make this work? Do I need install some plugin? I didn't find any docs on this.

UPDATE:

So I here is how I create my summary:

```
def finalize_graph(self, graph_building_context):
    tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)

    # the wealth tensor is of shape [B], where B is the batch size at runtime
    tf.summary.scalar('wealth', tf.reduce_mean(wealth))
    # uhmm, this tensor_summary doesn't work yet
    tf.summary.tensor_summary('wealth_tensor', wealth)
```

Then I use a `MonitoredTrainingSession`, by default it will save the summary, and I can see my `loss` and `wealth` scalar summry, but not this `wealth_tensor` summary.

Comment: I use a `MonitoredTrainingSession`, by default it will save the summary, and I can see my `loss` and `wealth` scalar summry, but not this `wealth_tensor` summary.

Comment: I'm not sure what is going wrong. Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41675152/3476748

Comment: @Chinni thanks, but I already read that question, I think it is not that reason. I use `MonitoredTrainingSession` which will automatically evaluate those summary op and write them to disk, and from the error I saw in tensorboard, they got that summary, but they say it is oddly not associated with any plugin, so they refuse to show it. But anyway, thank you.

Comment: Xiang, as you say, TensorBoard does not yet natively support visualizing  tensor summaries. I am also not aware of any third party plugin that does it.