# Visualize vector value at each step with Tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorboard

For debugging purposes I want to visualize the output vector of the NN at each step of the training process.

I tried to use TensorBoard with a tf.summary.tensor_summary:

```
available_outputs_summary = tf.summary.tensor_summary(name='Probability of move', tensor=available_outputs)
```

Which I use to write during each iteration step:

```
summary_str = available_outputs_summary.eval(feed_dict={X: obs})
file_writer.add_summary(summary_str, iteration)
```

But in TensorBoard when I click on the required tensor I won't see my data:

[image]

I know how to print every single value in the console with tf.Print but it's not conveniant...

Is there anything else I can do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your picture is the graph visualization. I believe graph visualization is not supposed to have any summaries - it just shows you the graph.

TensorBoard has other tabs for summaries including "scalar", "histogram", "distribution". Normally, you would look in these tabs for visualizations. However, base release of TensorBoard does not yet have a tab to visualize tensor summaries (there might be third-party plugins though).

Depending on the kind of visualization you want for you tensor, you have the following options:

- Create interesting scalar statistics that you care about, e.g. mean, std, etc.
- Use "histogram" and/or "distribution" tabs (https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/tensorboard_histograms).
- If your tensor is not very large and fixed size, you can create scalar summaries for each of its fields. See last answer in 
  [How to visualize a tensor summary in tensorboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41671817/how-to-visualize-a-tensor-summary-in-tensorboard)