# Keras: use Tensorboard with train_on_batch()

Tags: keras, tensorboard

For the keras functions `fit()` and `fit_generator()` there is the possibility of tensorboard visualization by passing a `keras.callbacks.TensorBoard` object to the functions. For the `train_on_batch()` function there obviously are no callback available. Are there other options in keras to create a Tensorboard in this case?

Comment: I found this github repro: https://gist.github.com/joelthchao/ef6caa586b647c3c032a4f84d52e3a11. However It did not work for me (no graphs shown in tensorboard)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that currently, the only option is to use TensorFlow code. In [this stack**overflow** answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37915182/4391129) I found a way to create a TensorBoard log manually.
Thus a code sample with the Keras `train_on_batch()` could look like this:

```
# before training init writer (for tensorboard log) / model
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(...)
model = ...

# train model
loss = model.train_on_batch(...)
summary = tf.Summary(value=[tf.Summary.Value(tag="loss", 
                                             simple_value=value), ])
writer.add_summary(summary)
```

**Note:** For this example in TensorBoard you have to choose *Horizontal Axis* "RELATIVE" as no step is passed to the summary.

Answer (score 13):

A possible way to create the TensorBoard callback, and drive it manually:

```python
# This example shows how to use keras TensorBoard callback
# with model.train_on_batch

import tensorflow.keras as keras

# Setup the model
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(...) # Add your layers
model.compile(...) # Compile as usual

batch_size=256

# Create the TensorBoard callback,
# which we will drive manually
tensorboard = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(
  log_dir='/tmp/my_tf_logs',
  histogram_freq=0,
  batch_size=batch_size,
  write_graph=True,
  write_grads=True
)
tensorboard.set_model(model)

# Transform train_on_batch return value
# to dict expected by on_batch_end callback
def named_logs(model, logs):
  result = {}
  for l in zip(model.metrics_names, logs):
    result[l[0]] = l[1]
  return result

# Run training batches, notify tensorboard at the end of each epoch
for batch_id in range(1000):
  x_train,y_train = create_training_data(batch_size)
  logs = model.train_on_batch(x_train, y_train)
  tensorboard.on_epoch_end(batch_id, named_logs(model, logs))

tensorboard.on_train_end(None)
```

Comment: This answer has additional steps than https://stackoverflow.com/a/44890471/579689. Does it have any advantages ?

Comment: I get the error TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration. keras version 2.2.4 / tensorflow version 1.13.1 / python 3.5.2.  Any suggestion to fix?

Comment: @grabbag your model probably only has one output, thus, `logs` is just a single loss value instead of a list of losses. If that's the case, change the second to last line to `tensorboard.on_epoch_end(batch_id, named_logs(model, [logs])`, i.e. add brackets around `logs` to wrap it in a list.