# add histogram summaries to tensorboard while using Keras train_on_batch

Tags: keras, tensorboard

I am using model.train_on_batch in keras in order to be able to handle different batches of input data differently. Essentially I cannot use model.fit

But I need to store histogram and images of activations and weights in Tensorboard. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: refer here, https://gist.github.com/joelthchao/ef6caa586b647c3c032a4f84d52e3a11
Exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44861149/keras-use-tensorboard-with-train-on-batch?rq=1

Comment: @UpasanaMittal That link is only for scalar summaries. I am looking for histograms and images to be stored in the summaries for Tensorboard. and I need to do it with Keras while using model.train_on_batch

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually by calling `summary.histogram` and passing the weights of each layer as below

```
with summary_writer.as_default():
  for layer in self.model.layers:
    for weight in layer.weights:
      tf.summary.histogram('weights/{}'.format(layer.name), weight, step=your_step)
```